# Spring Hibernate best way to handle modifying queries in a session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session

The issue:

Within a session if we have to use a modifying query such as an update, that change won't be visible within the session scope. One way to make it visible is to set the modifying query to clearAutomatically=true in the @Modifying annotation. The problem is that this change will effect all the changes in the same session, i.e. objects that were already save previous to that call will be voided and the changed won't be persisted once the transaction closes.

My question is: what's the best way to deal with this issue when clearAutomatically is not an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the Hibernate Session FLUSHMODE, your persistent objects may be synchronized with the persistence store before a query is executed by performing a flush() operation on the Session.  The flush process synchronizes database state with session state by detecting state changes and executing SQL statements, but it does not commit the transaction.

The default FLUSHMODE is AUTO, which is described as :

The Session is *sometimes* flushed before query execution in order to ensure that queries never return stale state. This is the default flush mode.  If you are getting stale data returned in your queries, flushing the Session manually should resolve your issue.

Comment: So, you're saying that if flush is executed before running a query with clearAutomatically=true, we won't lose any changes? What's the best flush mode to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: If you are using Hibernate like the subject suggests, then you do not need to use @Modifying meta-data, which looks to be JPA and not Hibernate. You just need to leave as AUTO flushmode, but if you are getting stale data in a query, execute a Session.flush() before running the query, though AUTO will flush before most queries. You will need to make sure you are not modifying detached or transient objects.

Comment: It seems to make sense. Thanks. I verified as well that it's only happening with updates and not with inserts but I cannot confirm if it's related. I'm going to accept it for now.